# How to get Joomla to change swf depending on language being used?

Tags: joomla, flash, translation

I'm new to this whole Joomla thing, and I'm trying to get an swf to change depending on what language the user is using. I'm using a language plugin which includes only two languages: English and Finnish. I've noticed when a user changes the language the URL changes with the language for example: index.php?lang=fi so in php i could probably use

```
`if ($_GET["lang"] == "fi"]
{
echo "";
}
if ($_GET["lang"] == "en"]
{
echo "";
}`
```

however for some reason the object tag isn't working so I had to use a module to play the swf. Somehow it "renders" the swf code while retreiving the swf file from the cache folder. I've looked at the code of the module and it doesn't make much sense at all, i can try posting it if someone wants to look at it. I can change images easily depending on the language and the text too of course, just the swf which is the main nav is in english all the time, any advice on how to tackle this would be much appreciated thank you!

Comment: object src="finnish.swf" for finnish and object src="english.swf" got blanked out in the echo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just made one swf in finnish and the english speakers will have to learn finnish